# Claire's impaired immune system

Tags: heroes

Presumably, Claire's power (rapid cellular regeneration) didn't kick in until adolescence otherwise she'd probably know about it beforehand. Given that she would have roughly 16 years, since she's well into high school before she discovers her ability, without her power, how does that account for an underdeveloped immune system (mentioned in the eclipse episode)? Wouldn't her immune system have spent at least 16 years develop without the crutch that rapid regeneration offers her?

Comment: I know it wasn't until the start of the series that she discovered her power, but is there any evidence that it didn't manifest before then? Micah's powers developed before puberty. I believe it was the movie Unbreakable where Bruce Willis had just never noticed that he had never been sick or injured before.

Comment: Given that she's a cheerleader and how accident-prone she seems to be, I doubt that she's never had cause to suspect her ability. Unbreakable is somewhat different in that Bruce Willis's character is simply invulnerable (doesn't take damage) whereas Claire can still be hurt but simply regenerates afterward.

Comment: @phantom42 But, the way she healed as extremely rapid like Wolverine. Where as Bruce Willis in Unbreakable was just simply... Unbreakable. She had to have skinned her knees or something like that as a child which would have been noticeable to not only herself, but to the people taking care of her (teachers, school nurses, etc.).

Comment: I wasn't drawing a parallel to their powers - just bringing up the idea of people having active powers for long periods of time without ever noticing them.

Comment: It's a good question. It might be that her abilities worked at a lesser level (ie, they surplanted her immune system) but became fully active after the first eclipse of the first two episodes. It would explain something like this. Unfortunately, since there isn't any real evidence and proof, it's only conjecture.

Comment: Was the "underdeveloped immune system" mentioned in the first season, or later? The writing became atrocious after the end of the first season, and their backstories often sucked. I'm not saying this to be lazy, but if the real answer is "bad writing" it doesn't make sense to try to contrive an explanation that fits the haphazard rules of the show.

Comment: I always assumed it was a case of her abilities taking the place of her autoimmune system, and once those abilities where turned off her natural immunities hadn't returned, similar to a "reset button" where she essentially had the immunities of a newborn.

Comment: @JohnO It was 3x10.  Season 3 had a sort-of mini writer reboot where they distanced themselves from the Season 2 disaster, and the overall quality increased pretty drastically.  Claire's "discovery" of her power was the part that always felt shoehorned in when they returned to it in Seasons 3 and 4.

Answer (score 6):

The premise of the question is unsound.  Claire's power manifested long before adolescence.  Her birth mother, Meredith Gordon, believed that Claire had died in an explosion and fire that Meredith caused.  This was established in the season one episode "Distractions."  Claire survived that fire because of her regenerative ability.  She was two years old at the time of the fire.

Comment: Didn't Noah rescue Claire from the fire before the explosion? I'll have to rewatch that episode, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Yawus Besides the episode, one of the official canon comics involved Claire's adoption after Noah's discovery of her.  I don't recall the specifics, but Noah and his boss knew she had a power at that time, and made a deal that if it ever manifested again, Noah would turn her over to the Company.